# Threejs Blender

Tags: three.js, webgl, blender

При экспорте json файлов из blender в threejs не подключаются текстуры, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема, это в коде нехватка чего-то или я экпорт в json как-то не так сделал в blender.

На сайте отображается просто модель как при обычном просмотре в blender, а надо чтобы просматривалось как при рендере

мой код подключения

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var controls;
var SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;
var loader, model;
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
var mscale = 10;

var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();


manager.onLoad = function () {
scene.add(group);
}

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(manager);

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, .1, 5000);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
});
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 15;
controls.maxDistance = 50;
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 1;
controls.addEventListener('change', render);

camera.position.x = 20;
camera.position.y = 15;
camera.position.z = 20;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

h1 = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.3);
h1.position.set(-300,200, -3000);
scene.add(h1);

var s1 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
s1.position.set(300, 300, -1000);
scene.add(s1);

var s2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
s2.position.set(-300, 300, 1000);
scene.add(s2);


loader.load(
    'json/grass.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/road.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/square.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/still.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/tree.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/less.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/light.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/dark.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);
loader.load(
    'json/game.json',
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        object.scale.set(mscale, mscale, mscale);
        object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        group.add( object );
    }
);

$("#container").append(renderer.domElement);
}

function render() {
group.rotation.y += 0.0005;
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
render();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
init();
animate();

$(window).resize(function () {
SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
});
```

Comment: Вопрос можно задать на форуме: https://discourse.threejs.org (форум англоязычный), приложив необходимые файлы с моделями.